# Use old smartphone touchscreen for raspberry

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, touchscreen

I have some old smartphones around. Is it possible to disassemble a smartphone and use the touchscreen as touchscreen(input and output) for my raspberry?
Is there something like adapters for different types of display standards which make it possible to connect it to the raspberry(no remote)? There are some touchscreens specific for rapi's available but i do not want to buy one if i could easily use a old smartphone.
Thanks for help and any ideas!

Comment: the money you'd spend on an adapter (if it existed) would probably be as much as buying a tried and tested screen

Comment: @JaromandaX maybe but it would be nice to learn something

Comment: @WastedFreeTime, this video does a good job explaining just how hard this is to do: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cl7rshPe-x4